# auth_user error with Django 1.8 and syncdb / migrate

Tags: python, django, buildout, django-syncdb, django-1.8

When upgrading to Django 1.8 (with zc.buildout) and running syncdb or migrate, I get this message:

`django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: relation "auth_user" does not exist`

One of my models contains django.contrib.auth.models.User:

```
user = models.ForeignKey(
    User, related_name='%(app_label)s_%(class)s_user',
    blank=True, null=True, editable=False
)
```

Downgrading to Django 1.7 removes the error.  Do I have to include the User object differently in Django 1.8?

Comment: On my environment, this only happen using `Postgre`.

Answer (score 99):

I fix this by running auth first, then the rest of my migrations:

```
python manage.py migrate auth
python manage.py migrate
```

Comment: Your auth app should already be near the top in INSTALLED_APPS, i.e. 'django.contrib.admin', if its in the correct order the above shouldn't make a difference.

Comment: I get `relation "django_site" does not exist` .  I'm on django 1.8.2.  I tried a few different apps in my project and always got the same error, then I ran `python manage.py migrate` again, and lo and behold it worked.

Answer (score 19):

On my environment, I fix this running `makemigrations` on all apps that have relationship with `django.contrib.auth.models`:

```
manage.py makemigrations app_with_user_relation
manage.py migrate
```

Comment: I had the same issue and this solution worked. Passing from Django 1.7.X to 1.8.1

Comment: I can confirm that this still works, and for use with Heroku.

Comment: This solution worked for me in D2.2 for a very non-related issue. Was trying to run unit tests and kept getting this error. Turned out  there was a held-up migration in the users app that needed to be run manually (i.e. `makemigrations users`) and suddenly my unit test module started functioning.

Answer (score 8):

If you are using heroku like I was run

```
heroku run python manage.py makemigrations
```

This will likely give you a message saying there are now changes. Ignore that then run

```
heroku run python manage.py migrate
```

this will give you some output suggesting something has been done.
Finally run

```
heroku run python manage.py createsuperuser
```

Answer (score 8):

This problem is contained by running "makemigrations" for all apps, that have not yet been migrated, i.e. apps that do not yet have an "initial_0001.py" file in their migrations directory.

This is done (in our case we use a makefile) by running for each of these apps:

```
manage.py makemigrations app_name
```

Once that is done, you can execute:

```
manage.py migrate
```

as usual.

The underlying cause for this is that for some reason

```
manage.py makemigrations
```

does *not* always create these initial migrations if they are not already there. And that leads to the mentioned error.

On the contrary,

```
manage.py makemigrations app_name
```

*does* always create them (if not already there). Unfortunately I cannot fathom the reasons for this asymmetry.

Comment: In which directory do you run the command? I get the error "Can't open file manage.py".

Comment: You should run that command inside the directory that contains the file "manage.py". You can try the following 2 alternatives: 1) prepend the command with dot-slash, like so: "./manage.py makemigrations" or 2) prepend with the python executable, like so: "python manage.py makemigrations". Good luck.

Comment: But where is this located?

Comment: In the same directory as where your app directories are located, see here for a directory layout (I cannot paste it here), look for "Creating a project":  https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/intro/tutorial01/. If you don't have it anymore, you should  to replace it. Btw.: you can use "django-admin" as well, which should be in your Python path, see also: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/django-admin/

Answer (score 4):

To fix this problem here is what I did:

1) Find all foreign key relation fields like OneToOneField, ForeignKey and ManyToManyFields in your project, including any reusable apps that are referring to `auth.User` or import User and set it to settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL as above. At minimum use:

```
'auth.User'
```

2) For all the models that have the above, make sure the models have a valid django migration (not south). If they have south migrations, rename the directory to migrations_south and then run the makemigrations command for that app:

```
./manage.py makemigrations affected_app
```

Sometimes there is a django migrations folder under a different name, not the default `migrations` directory. In such cases, reference this via `MIGRATION_MODULES` in your settings.py:

```
MIGRATION_MODULES = {'filer': 'filer.migrations_django'}
```

Since the issue was hard to find on larger projects, I commented out all custom apps in `INSTALLED_APPS` in settings.py and ran the test command, since it will run migrate and try to re-create the database for you:

```
./manage.py test
```

Looks like that fixed it for me. I'm not sure if step 1 is mandatory or just best practice. But you definitely need to convert the apps to migrations.

Cheers!

PS. Be ready for what's coming in [Django 1.9](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/releases/1.9/). The syncdb command will be removed.  The legacy method of syncing apps without migrations is removed, and migrations are compulsory for all apps.

Answer (score 0):

Try referring to the User using this

```
from django.conf import settings
user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, related_name='%(app_label)s_%(class)s_user', blank=True, null=True, editable=False)
```

Comment: Doesn't work for me. I have no migrations, just trying to run ./manage.py test and the the fail right away when migrate is run: django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: relation "auth_user" does not exist

Comment: The fix is to have your models that rely on foreign keys to auth_model also under migrations. Good practice overall since syncdb is gone in Django 1.9

Answer (score 0):

I've migrated an old Django 1.6 project to Django 1.8 and previously we've  used syncdb to migrate the database and we did **not have initial migration steps** for all apps in our project. With Django 1.8, you'll need a working database migrations. Running

```
manage.py makemigrations <app_name>
```

for all apps in our project fixed our problems.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you have found the answer and resolved the problem, but I wanted to point out that, in my case, the above problem was solved by dropping the database and re-creating it again, with the full privileges of the users. I was able to do this because I'm working on a non-production environment, but doing this on a staging environment is not a good idea, so be careful.

Im using `python 2.7.12` and following are the specifications of my virtualenv:

```
Django==1.10.5
django-crispy-forms==1.6.1
django-registration-redux==1.4
djangorestframework==3.5.3
olefile==0.44
packaging==16.8
Pillow==4.0.0
psycopg2==2.6.2
```

Comment: Thank you very much "cavpollo" for the correction. it looks definitely better.

Comment: Dropping and recreating the database was the only thing that worked for me. After that, I ran python manage.py migrate, then the problem was fixed. All I had to do after that was create another superuser.