# Why do I get a "auth_user does not exist"error when running "migrate" on a newly created django project with "registration redux" app installed?

Tags: django, registration

Given a newly created django project with the following installed apps:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = (
'django.contrib.admin',
'django.contrib.auth',
'django.contrib.contenttypes',
'django.contrib.sessions',
'django.contrib.messages',
'django.contrib.staticfiles',
'registration',
)
```

When I run ./manage.py migrate for the first time I get the following error:

````
Operations to perform:
  Synchronize unmigrated apps: staticfiles, messages, registration
  Apply all migrations: sessions, admin, auth, contenttypes
Synchronizing apps without migrations:
  Creating tables...
    Creating table registration_registrationprofile
    Running deferred SQL...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./manage.py", line 10, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/Users/tcosta/Virtualenvs/django_project/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 338, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/Users/tcosta/Virtualenvs/django_project/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 330, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/Users/tcosta/Virtualenvs/django_project/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 390, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "/Users/tcosta/Virtualenvs/django_project/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 441, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "/Users/tcosta/Virtualenvs/django_project/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/migrate.py", line 179, in handle
    created_models = self.sync_apps(connection, executor.loader.unmigrated_apps)
  File "/Users/tcosta/Virtualenvs/django_project/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/migrate.py", line 317, in sync_apps
    cursor.execute(statement)
  File "/Users/tcosta/Virtualenvs/django_project/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 79, in execute
    return super(CursorDebugWrapper, self).execute(sql, params)
  File "/Users/tcosta/Virtualenvs/django_project/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 64, in execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/Users/tcosta/Virtualenvs/django_project/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 97, in __exit__
    six.reraise(dj_exc_type, dj_exc_value, traceback)
  File "/Users/tcosta/Virtualenvs/django_project/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 62, in execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql)
django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: relation "auth_user" does not exist```
````

It seems Django is trying to create the registration tables before the user table.

This erros does not happen if I comment the registration app and run migrate and then uncomment the registration app and run migrate again. However, that's not the right way of doing it, right?

Comment: Django migrations should be able to specify dependencies to determine order, so the `registration` migration could probably use a `dependency` to `auth.User`. Since it's a library, I'm not really sure what the solution is here. Perhaps the order of `INSTALLED_APPS`?

Comment: I've already changed the order of INSTALLED APPS but it didn't work! :( Thanks by the way.

Comment: To "solve" it I had to create all migrations for all apps and then I launched a migrate and it worked. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29689365/auth-user-error-with-django-1-8-and-syncdb-migrate (Pedro's asnwer)

Comment: I am having same issue. `python manage.py migrate` migrates all apps in correct order with auth first on mysql5.6 but when I move to mysql5.7, I see this issue.

Answer (score 27):

After updating my Django version, I got this error and fix as running these two lines:

```
python manage.py migrate auth
python manage.py migrate
```

auth_user table inside auth model should run first I guess.

Comment: And if it looks like manage.py is packed away somewhere, it's okay, you can still use it- 

# python /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/graphite/manage.py migrate auth

Comment: At long last, the answer I needed.  A gazillion answers saying to run `manage makemigrations` and `manage migrate` but this is the first I've seen that mentions `manage migrate auth`.  Is this due to originating my app with Django 1.6 and upgrading along the way to 2.0 now?  Or are most of these answers just incomplete?

Comment: More people need to see this answer. It solved my issue after a lot of searching. Thank you.

Answer (score 5):

The problem is avoided when you do as Pedro Wagner suggests ([auth_user error with Django 1.8 and syncdb / migrate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29689365/auth-user-error-with-django-1-8-and-syncdb-migrate/)):

Make sure that for all your apps, there exist initial migrations files by running:

```
manage.py makemigrations my_app
```

I'd do it not only for those that depend on auth because I think the problem is more general.

The root cause for this behaviour seems to me that for some reason

```
manage.py makemigrations
```

does not always create the initial migrations if they are not already there, *contrary* to:

```
manage.py makemigrations my_app
```

Unfortunately I cannot fathom the reasons for this asymmetry.

Comment: This was super Helpful

Answer (score 4):

I think you just forgot to migrate your auth models. However, to do that, just type in the following command on your terminal.

```
python manage.py migrate
```

or

```
python manage.py migrate auth
```

Hope this settles your error in the program.

Answer (score 1):

I think you needed to run:

`python manage.py syncdb`

and potentially you need to setup some dependencies? Probably not necessary after syncdb.

### South 1 style (Django < 1.7)

```
class Migration:

    depends_on = (
        ("accounts", "0001"),
    )

    def forwards(self):
        ....
```

### South 2 style (Django >= 1.7)

```
from django.db import migrations, models

class Migration(migrations.Migration):

    dependencies = [("accounts", "0001")]
```

Answer (score 0):

Once you create a migration for your app it will automatically add the necessary dependencies. So in this case just run `./manage.py makemigrations registration`.

Please check the registration/migrations/0001_initial.py file and you should see something like this:

```
dependencies = [
    migrations.swappable_dependency(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL),
]
```

This means you need to create migrations for all your apps with any kind of dependency.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem too, solved it by replacing old registration with one that includes [pull #25](https://github.com/macropin/django-registration/pull/25):

```
pip install git+https://github.com/macropin/django-registration.git@v1.2c0
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case, this has been resolved re-adding some modules in INSTALLED_APPS that had been removed. As a consequence, some tables in the database were confusing the migration scheme and then ruining the `test` command because the default database was containing those previous migrations.

Fixed re-adding the modules, `allauth` and other related submodules in my case.

Answer (score -2):

you have not migrated your models

python manage.py makemigrations my_app_name

for mac os

python3 manage.py makemigrations my_app